# Windows bad::alloc on std::vector push_back

Tags: c++, qt, window, std, eigen

i have a working c++ code in linux 64bit which i export in QT Windows 32bit (virtual machine). For that in created a static library with QT in windows for my program and included this in my QT GUI. The problem is that my program crash when i run my GUI.

The struct is defined somewhere else with Eigen::Vector2d and int, no pointer.

My program crash with this error

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Debuggen beendet
```

That means that i dont have enough Memory free but on my windows i have 1 GB left and my programm needs only 32MB.

I have no idea what i can do to solve this problem? anyone has an idea?

### I debuged this and i dont understand this error in this function

EDIT

```
class B {
    std::vector<A> vec;
    void add(int value, Eigen::Vector2d point);
}
    B::add(int value, Eigen::Vector2d point)
      Class A;
      A.value=value;
      A.point=point;
      vec.push_back(A);
    }


class A{     (only header file)
public:
  int value;
  Eigen::Vector2d point;
}

class C(){
void AddSomethingtoB(B& output)
}
```

class A,B,C are my static library and are included in my QT Project.

Now i do on my Mainwindow on an action

```
   int main(){
    C c_class;
    B b_class;
    c_class.AddSomethingtoB(b_class);
    }
```

really funny think, when i do this like that i can add one element after that the size of my vector is 1431655766.

But when i do

```
   int main(){
    C c_class;
    B b_class;
    std::cout << "size" << b_class.vec.size() << std::endl;
    c_class.AddSomethingtoB(b_class);
    }
```

my program is running without any problem. What is the problem here? Can my "main" not reserve enough space for my vector ? Or is that an initialization problem? I have no idea

Comment: Are you sure you haven't pushed more than you realize onto the vector?  At the time of the exception, what was `vec.size()`?

Comment: Somehow I'm unsure whether `Namespace::Struct` is a high-quality class that doesn't have some bogus kind of copy constructor and/or destructor.

Comment: I'm half tempted to ask whether the B  object was properly initialized

Comment: i added a few new thinks above, it is a class not a Struct sry and i saw that the size is 1431655766, but this is the first time i add something...

Comment: @Hunk: Can you clarify that for me? The vector claims that it has 1431655766 elements, but you believe that it should be empty?

Comment: I edit a lot of thinks above. The funny thing is when i add one element the size of my vector is full. I always working with references and the initialization of Class C and B is outside of the library. And thank you for your help

Comment: Can you post actual code that we can compile? It doesn't look like there's anything related to Qt in what you posted, so I'd assume you can post  a short, simple console program that still shows the problem.

Comment: ok i think i got the error. I used the Eigen command #define EIGEN_DONT_ALIGN_STATICALLY before Eigen/Core but not in my class A because. But i dont have a good explanation what happened there, normaly i get a error from Eigen with this 32bit problem